# Example of form_for custom REST action and .haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, form-for

I'm redeveloping a .haml form_for for an #edit_profile view to accommodate a controller where the #edit and #update methods have already been claimed. I had the form working before with the standard methods, but apparently Rails was doing a lot behind the scenes that I must now specify and I'm stuck.

I'm the sort who learns by mimicry and breaking things, so I need an example. I've googled around without any luck, so I'm hoping someone here can point me at one. Specifically: where do I put the method::patch and update_profile paths?

I just need the haml. I've established that the controller works with the new methods (#edit_profile and #update_profile), so all I have to do is connect the form to the controller.

Here's the repository if anybody needs that:
https://github.com/sidhene/MetPlus_PETS/blob/Update_CompanyPerson-%23146/app/views/company_people/edit_profile.html.haml

Thanks in advance,
A

Answer (score 1):

The `url` argument needs to be to the `update_profile` action instead of the `update` action.  Change `update_company_person_path(@company_person)` to `update_profile_company_person_path(@company_person)`

**Edit:** Your [config/routes](https://github.com/sidhene/MetPlus_PETS/blob/Update_CompanyPerson-%23146/config/routes.rb#L55) looks correct, but run `rake routes` just ot be sure.  You should see a line with `update_profile_company_person` and `PATCH` in it.

Comment: Thanks, I think we (I'm part of a team) confirmed with rake routes already. I used Rspec tests to verify the controller. Assuming the tests are good, would at least one of them have failed if the routes were wrong?

Comment: Integration (capybara, for instance) tests would have caught this.  Controller tests would not because 1) they don't render views by default, 2) even if you call the `render_views` method, it would have passed because the code is syntactically correct, and 3) When you test controller methods, you're bypassing the router, so the code for testing the `update_profile` action names that action instead of relying on the cod ein a view.

Answer (score 1):

[`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) takes a value and populates its other HTML attributes from it (`action` / `method` etc):

> `form_for` generates an appropriate form tag and yields a form builder object that knows the model the form is about.
>
> As you see, the HTML reflects knowledge about the resource in several spots, like the path the form should be submitted to, or the names of the input fields.

The whole *point* of `form_for` is that you're meant to pass a *resource* / *object* to it.

Populated from the model, this object / resource will contain an array of data, such as the `Class` name etc, which Rails then uses to populate the form.

As per the docs:

> ...to create a new person you typically set up a new instance of Person in the `PeopleController#new` action, `@person`, and in the view template pass that object to `form_for`:
>
> ```
> <%= form_for @person do |f| %>
> ```
>
> The HTML generated for this would be (modulus formatting):
>
> ```
> <form action="/people" class="new_person" id="new_person" method="post">
> ```

---

Thus, if you wanted to infer a different `path` / `url` for your form, you'll need to explicitly define it:

```
= form_for @profile, url: profile_update_path(@profile) do |f|
```

--

In your case, you're using a `nested resource`, which means that you have to pass both parts of the route as an **array**:

```
 = form_for [:company_person, @company_person] do |f|
```

This should work fine for you.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like exactly what I need. More soon after I have time to "unpack" it...

Comment: it looks like the second example you offer for the nested resource doesn't include the custom call. If so, how do I phrase that?

Comment: What do you mean by custom call?